# What exactly does calling just getClass() method in an abstract class definition do - also related to threadsafety?

Tags: java, spring, synchronized

I'm a java noob so pardon my ignorance in the subject.
I was instructed at work to update some code to make it threadsafe. I was pointed to the bits of code that would need to be changed. You will find my questions below.

There is an abstract class called: AbstractServiceProcessor
In this abstract class there is a call to getClass() as shown in the below code excerpt:

```
finally
        {
            synchronized (getClass())
            {
                progressMeter.mark(item.getChangeList().size());
                dsTimer.stop();
            }
        }
```

1st Question: What is `synchronized (getClass())` supposed to do?

2nd Question: I was instructed to change that to `synchronized (AbstractServiceProcessor.class)`
             What is that going to do? Why was I instructed to change to this?

Thank you in advance for your explanations.

Comment: Start by understanding [what a `synchronized` block does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and what `getClass()` returns. You should also understand what a `.class` literal is.

Comment: thanks Sotirios for your prompt response as usual. Could you provide your 2 cents on this?

Comment: Why dont you ask those questions to person who ask you to do so ?

Comment: That was my 2 cents :). The answer is in the documentation for the various keywords in my previous comment. Look up the javadoc for `Object#getClass()`. Read the tutorial on synchronization. Look up what a class literal is. There's a lot to go through here and it wouldn't fit nicely into an answer IMO.

Comment: @Vash: because I would get fired! :)

Comment: @TazMan Really? You shouldn't really work in an organization, where you get fired to ask question. And I don't think you'll really get fired for asking this question.

Comment: You should **really** read the documents I asked you to read if you haven't already. Stackoverflow is not a replacement for reading documentation.

Comment: @TazMan, You should have more trust in your supervisor. It possible that he do not have time to answer to all of your quesions. But he should know what you are capable of. Only in that way he is able to assigne you proper task with proper feedback. And for sure you will learn more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is `synchronized(getClass())` supposed to do?

It gets a lock on the `Class` object returned by `getClass()`. However, you should never use that, as already being instructed. The issue is, that `synchronized` block might lock on a different `Class` objects, based on which subclass object the method is being invoked. As `getClass()` returns the *runtime type* of the object. Due to that, two different threads, which are not supposed to execute that block at the same time, will eventually end up doing that, as the lock is not the same. That may cause serious bug in you application.

> I was instructed to change that to `synchronized(AbstractServiceProcessor.class)`. What is that going to do? Why was I instructed to change to this?

I've already explained why you're instructed to do this change. Now, synchronizing on `AbstractServiceProcessor.class` ensures that you always lock on the same `Class` object, no matter on which subclass object you are invoking the method.

Comment: Thank you Rohit. What is returned by getClass()? Is it the actual subclass of the abstract class this method is called in? What I don't understand is, why wouldn't I want to do this `getClass()` in the abstract class? Shouldn't I be acquiring the lock on the implementing class?

Comment: @TazMan You understand that a superclass reference can refer to any of its subclass objects right? `getClass()` returns the `Class` instance of that actual subclass object. It is decided at runtime. And generally, you won't want to lock on the objects that you're not sure of what it is going to be. Abstract class is irrelevant here. This is case for all such usage of `synchronized` block.

Comment: How can a getClass() get the subclass? It should get the class of the object that is currently calling getClasss

Comment: @TazMan No it doesn't. It gets you the class of the actual object. Try calling that method on subclass object.